# I know that generators in Python maintain the local state. What are the implications of this?

Tags: python, scope, generator, local-variables

I know that generators in Python maintain the local state.  I have read the example involving the Fibonacci sequence in PEP255.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/

However, I still don't understand the implications of this.  Namely,

1) why is this useful?

2) what would happen if generators do NOT maintain local state? Can you show me via a simple example in code?

3) does maintaining local state relate to a generator's ability to save memory by producing only one value at a time during iteration, rather than storing the entire iterable object in memory?

4) does maintaining local state have any disadvantages?

Comment: How do you imagine a generator to work that *doesn’t* maintain state…? Or perhaps, what do you think “maintaining state” means?

Comment: Your question is too broad, and 1 and 2 are clearly explained in the Fibonacci example in PEP255 you linked to. The answer to 3 is yes. Furthermore, you can't always generate the entire iterable as it can be infinite (such as the Fibonacci series). You should clarify 4: Disadvantages when compared to _what_? You can't implement generators without keeping some kind of state.

Comment: @deceze: This is my understanding of "maintaining local state": Any variable assignments made within the generator function do not affect variable assignments outside of the generator function. Am I wrong? If so, please correct me.

Comment: @Selcuk: Please forgive my incompetence, but I have read that Fibonacci example several times, and I still don't get it. It seems like this is the key statement: "fib continues after the yield with all local state intact. a and b then become 1 and 1, and fib loops back to the yield, yielding 1 to its invoker." I don't understand the phrase "with all local state intact". What does that mean, and how does it relate to the utility of this generator?

Comment: @Iterator516 You seem to be confused about the term "maintaining local state". It means that all internal state (such as local variables, including loop indices), is preserved until a subsequent call to the function. This way the function "remembers" the last state and keeps running from where it left off. That's how it returns the "next" Fibo number. If it wasn't for a generator function (i.e. `yield` keyword) it would always return 1 on each call.

Comment: @Selcuk Ah - that's very helpful, thank you. You're right - I did misunderstand what "maintaining local state" means. I appreciate you correcting me.

Comment: @Selcuk To answer your earlier question about #4, let's compare generators to iterators. A generator maintains its local state, while an iterator does not. Are there any advantages to using an iterator over a generator?

Comment: @Selcuk I have created a new question to address #4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359333/are-there-any-advantages-of-iterators-over-generators-in-python