# Are there any advantages of non-generator iterators over generators in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

In the code below, `i1` is an iterator.

```
def sq(x):

    y = []

    for i in x:
        y.append(i**2)

    return y

l1 = range(5)
s1 = sq(l1)
i1 = iter(s1)
```

I can write a generator for the same squaring operation.  In the code below, `g1` is a generator.

```
def sqg(x):

    for i in x:

        yield i**2

g1 = sqg(l1)
```

I know that generators use less code and are simpler to read and write.  I know that generators also run faster because they maintain their local states.

Are there any advantages to using `i1` over `g1`?

Comment: Note that in the first you're strictly creating an entire list, whereas you aren't in the second. Are you talking about advantages in general, or in this scenario in particular? It would depend on the exact use case and what data you already have available to you.

Comment: Generators **are iterators**. It's hard to tell what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I ask about advantages in general. I provided this example to have something concrete to refer to. If it's too hard to talk in general, let's talk about this particular case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you're right: Generators are a subset of iterators. I'm referring to non-generator iterators. Are there any advantages to non-generator iterators over generators? I have modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `sq(l1)`, inside `sq`, a list `y` is populated. This consumes memory whose size is proportional to the size of `x` once exhausted.

In the second case, when you call `sqg(l1)`, `sqg` does not have any internal list used to store the results. It directly yields computed values, making the memory it consumes constant and independent of the size of `x` once exhausted.

As for advantages of non-generator iterators over generators, I don't believe there are performance advantages, but there could be structural advantages. A generator (a type of iterator like you noted) is defined to be an iterator returned by calling a function with `yield` statements inside of it. That means that you cannot add any additional methods that can be called to the object representing the generator, because this special type of iterator is given to you implicitly.

On the other hand, an iterator has a looser definition: an object with a `__next__` method and an `__iter__` method returning `self`. You could make a class `Squares` that follows the previous criteria for an iterator, and in order to get an instance to this iterator, you would have to explicitly instantiate `Squares`. **Because you have control over the attributes of the iterator** returned to you, you could add instance methods returning internal state of that iterator that aren't expressed through `__next__`, whereas with a generator you're locked into the generator object provided to you implicitly. Often a generator will do the job, but sometimes you need to use a non-generator iterator to get the control you need past the functionality provided by `__next__`.

In this specific case, I don't believe you need the explicit control given to you by using a non-generator iterator, so it would be better to use a generator.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. My question is about ADVANTAGES of iterators over generators, not vice versa. Your answer - while entirely true - answers the opposite question.

Comment: @Iterator516 Sorry I completely misread your question, see if I answered it now.

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are advantages of creating a list `s1` over a generator - it has a defined length, you can index and slice it, and you can iterate through it multiple times without re-creating it. Maybe you don't count these as advantages of the non-generator iterator, though.

Another difference is that an iterator based on a list involves doing all the work upfront and then caching the results, while the generator does the work one step at a time. If the processing task is resource-intensive, then the list approach will cause an initial pause while the list is generated, then run faster (because you only have to retrieve the results from memory; also consider that the results could be cached in a file, for example). The generator approach would have no initial pause but would then run slower as it generates each result.